# After upgrade to 20.04: luks doesn't open my disk on boot; cryptroot/crypttab is empty, cryptsetup doesn't recognize the crypttab entry

Tags: luks, initramfs, cryptsetup, initrd, cryptroot

after upgrading to 20.04, my encrypted disk doesn't get decrypted on boot. I'm not asked for any password, so it obviously can't find any partition and boots into initrd prompt.

What might be the reason: `/cryptroot/crypttab` in the initrd image is completely empty.

I can open luks manually and chroot into the system. This is the content of my `/etc/crypttab` in the real root directory:

`nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=<some uuid> none luks`

(The UUIDs are all correct, everywhere)

When I run `update-initramfs -c -k all`, the output is:

`cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'nvme0n1p3_crypt' not found in /etc/crypttab`

Which is a bit weird, because it's exactly the target name of the only single entry in that file. It's also listed in `/dev/mapper` as a link to `../dm-0` which also seems to be correct.

I tried renaming the device to `crypt` only using `dmsetup rename ...` but that didn't help of course.

I assume that this is the root cause of my problem.

Answer (score 8):

Fyi, I got it fixed.
It was so weird, I would've never find out if someone didn't have told me.

The problem is with the file `/etc/crypttab`: It needs an EOF at the end!

Whoah! How can this be? This is the first time in the last 25 years that some linux needs ecpects an EOF in a text file. Gosh!

Anyway, now it's fixed, after more than one week testing.

Comment: What do you mean by an EOF? That's not a character. A newline? A null byte?

Comment: Assuming that you mean a newline character (\n), then yes, some things in linux are weird when you don't have a trailing "\n", specially lower level stuff. That's why most modern text editors will automatically add one for you even if you don't add it manually.

Comment: crontab needs newline to work as well, so… You just did not happen to stumble about it for the last 25y;)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the generation routine:
https://salsa.debian.org/gpiccoli/cryptsetup/-/blob/master/debian/functions#L526

Another gotcha (others may say it's intended) is that your `/etc/crypttab` TARGET (= name) must be the one currently used for the root you intend to generate the initramfs for.

Eg: If you:

> `luks open` **foo**
> `mount /dev/mapper/foo`
> `chroot`
> `update-initramfs`

Then `foo's` `etc/crypttab's` `TARGET` **must** be **foo** too otherwise you'd see:

> `cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'foo' not found in /etc/crypttab`

Although it's barely visible with `update-initramfs -v`.

Comment: I encountered this same problem after trying to repair a kernel install from a `chroot` using a recovery disk. To mount the root volume, I first ran `cryptsetup open /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt`. As you mentioned, the name you choose here is important. To match the Ubuntu default, you have to add `_crypt` to the device name in this way. If you name it incorrectly, `update-initramfs` from a recovery disk `chroot` will create a boot image that doesn't correctly decrypt and mount root at boot.